# Mule batch job w/ vm-queue in clustered environment: Could not deserialize object

Tags: queue, mule, cluster-computing

The code below is used to read from a TSV file, transform the data, and write to a database. All the operations on the data (transformation, insert) work fine, but there is an error in the outbound queue in the batch job, and it never returns. This works fine in a single-server environment; the error occurs when deployed as a mule cluster.

Here's the code:

```
<sub-flow name="quantile-forecast-transfer_writeToDataWarehouse_SubFlow">
    <logger message="Truncating database table lwstg.salescast.lokad_forecast_quantile" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger - Truncating Table"/>
    <db:update config-ref="MSSqlServer_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database - Truncate Table">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[truncate table some.table;]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:update>
    <set-payload value="#[flowVars.fileContents]" mimeType="application/java" doc:name="Set Payload - flowVars.fileContents"/>
    <request-reply doc:name="Request-Reply">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="${lokad.qiq}" doc:name="Queue - Batch In"/>
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="${lokad.qoq}" doc:name="Queue - Batch Out"/>
    </request-reply>
</sub-flow>
<batch:job name="quantile-forecast-transfer_writeToDatabase_Batch">
    <batch:threading-profile maxThreadsActive="6" maxThreadsIdle="12" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
    <batch:input>
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="${lokad.qiq}" doc:name="Queue - Batch In"/>
        <flow-ref name="quantile-forecast-transfer_transformData_SubFlow" doc:name="quantile-forecast-transfer_transformData_SubFlow"/>
        <logger message="Writing data to database table some.table" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger - Writing Data"/>
    </batch:input>
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="Insert">
            <batch:commit size="5000" doc:name="Batch Commit">
                <db:insert config-ref="MSSqlServer_Database_Configuration" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database - Bulk Insert Quantile">
                    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO some.table (id, reorder_point, processing_status, batch_id)VALUES (#[payload.id],#[payload.reorder_point],#[payload.processing_status],#[payload.batch_id]);]]></db:parameterized-query>
                </db:insert>
            </batch:commit>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:process-records>
    <batch:on-complete>
        <logger message="Completed quantile transfer" level="INFO" doc:name="Log completed transfer"/>
        <logger message="Finished database insert to lwstg.salescast.lokad_forecast_quantile. Number of failed records: #[payload.failedRecords]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger - Report"/>
        <validation:is-false message="There were #[payload.failedRecords] records that failed in insert to the lwstg.salescast.lokad_forecast_quantile table" expression="#[payload.failedRecords &gt; 0]" doc:name="Validate no failures"/>
        <set-payload value="#[&quot;something serializeable&quot;.getBytes()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger message="Payload is: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="${lokad.qoq}" doc:name="Queue - Batch Out"/>
    </batch:on-complete>
</batch:job>
```

Here's the abbreviated stack trace:

org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy - Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Could not deserialize object
org.mule.api.serialization.SerializationException: Could not deserialize object

...

Caused by: org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot load class 'int'

...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot load class 'int'

Comment: Hi Josh, I am facing this exact same issue in my environment. Running Mule 3.8.5. Did you ever find a resolution to this? I know it was some time ago but I'd appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. We were using queues to try and boost performance by distributing processing between multiple servers. Since we couldn't get it to work, we attempted another approach.

Comment: We actually raised it with Mule in the end and it turned out it was an issue with the apache commons lang module. Updated in 3.9.* or you can patch your installation.